# AWS Serverless Lambda unencoded character

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a simple serverless function on aws lambda

The QA team decided to create a curl request for testing with character "^"
when it is not encoded ie:

```
curl -X GET   'https://lambda.com/call?id=inva^lid'
```

so this call doesn't even get to my code as it returns nothing.
Blank, none.

Any ideas how to solve this?
on lambda? ApiGateway? CloudFront?

Any idea will be great!

Thanks!

verbose curl request:

```
*   Trying 54.230.159.190...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (1.1.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):


* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.example.com
*  start date: Feb 26 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 26 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fb1cc00a400)
> GET /call?id=inva^lid HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: application/json
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Postman-Token: b730c1f2-b8ab-4eeb-b097-99f7d812434a
> api-key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 400
< content-length: 0
< date: Thu, 31 May 2018 12:38:54 GMT
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 xxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-id: -Kn-xxxxxx==
<
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

and now I see this in the log "Error from cloudfront"

so any idea how to resolve that?

now the same call with `--http1.1`

```
*   Trying 1.1.1.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (1.1.1.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):

* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.example.com
*  start date: Feb 26 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 26 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /call?id==inva^lid HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: application/json
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Postman-Token: b730c1f2-b8ab-4eeb-b097-99f7d812434a
> api-key: xxxxxxxxx
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 14:37:26 GMT
< X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: xxxxxxxxx-J60xxc0TI4MOjQ==
<
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
```

Comment: To start, add the `-v` option to curl.

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot added the log and noticed "Error from cloudfront" any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a bug, somewhere, but hard to say where, yet.  Switch curl to HTTP/1.1 with `--http1.1` and repeat, please.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot pasted the call response, looks quite similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disregard any specific meaning of `X-Cache: Error from CloudFront` because it is a standard header added by CloudFront to any request that it handles, where the HTTP response code is >= 400.  The CloudFront infrastructure handles transport of requests for some other services, including API Gateway Edge-Optimized endpoints and S3 Transfer Acceleration (and you can generate that same header by trying to make an accelerated connection to a bucket that doesn't have the transfer acceleration feature enabled).  It essentially means "CloudFront handled this request, and something didn't work" -- but it doesn't give you a hint as to what, exactly, because the error could have been internal or external to CloudFront and this header would be present in both cases.

To narrow this down, I did some further testing.  As it turns out, CloudFront has no problem with the `^` character in the query string parameter.  Confirmed with a CloudFront distribution and a custom origin, this character in this position is not an issue.

But API Gateway chokes on it.

Confirmed this with a Regional API Endpoint (which doesn't use CloudFront for transport), API Gateway chokes on the `^` and returns... almost nothing.

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 15:54:59 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
<
```

There's a documented case of something similar...

> The plain text pipe character (|) is not supported for any request URL query string and must be URL-encoded.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html

Putting an unescaped pipe character into the query string triggers the exact same behavior, so this appears to be a limitation in API Gateway -- it's rejecting this character and calling it a "Bad Request," which means the client request is malformed.

It appears that API Gateway has the same issue with `^`.

In both cases, the rejection occurs so early in the API Gateway infrastructure that not only does your code not see it... it's so early that the request does not even make it to the CloudWatch logs for the API endpoint.

Based on that, is *possible* that it may not even count toward your [throttling limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html) because API Gateway may have stopped parsing the request before it even associated it to your API, specifically </speculation>.

If you url-escape the `^` as `%5E`, then API Gateway has no problem.  In fact, it even correctly decodes it and shows the value in the logs:

```
Method request query string: {id==inva^lid}
```

So I'd say your QA team has found an issue with API Gateway -- you'll need to url-escape the `^` character in query strings.  But it is returning a valid HTTP error code... just no response body.

Comment: You have just saved my day! I've been debugging this all day. Thank you so much!